# opening app on click of link in mobile browser ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking

I have an application wherein there is a signUp class so when a user registers himself he get a verification email.So currently when the verification link is clicked it opens an html page.
Now i want that when the verification link is clicked on mobile browser it should open my app with a particular page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [custom url scheme in ios](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

in app delegate implement following method to handle parameters

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
        sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  NSLog(@"Calling Application Bundle ID: %@", sourceApplication);
  NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
  NSLog(@"URL query: %@", [url query]);

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: hi @gyani, if my url starts with https://test.mail.com then  what would be scheme i need to add in the info.plist

Comment: you have to create custom url like yourAppName://test.mail.com and you have to implement custom url scheme to detect it